# Prove that the sequence is purely periodic

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m$ be a fixed integer greater $1$. The sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ is defined as follows: $$x_i = \begin{cases}2^i, \quad &\text{ if } 0 \leq i \leq m-1;\\\sum_{j=1}^m x_{i-j}, \quad &\text{ if } i \geq m.\end{cases}$$ Consider the terms of the sequence taken modulo $m$. Prove that the sequence is purely periodic.

I noticed that since the sequence is infinite in length and there are $m^m$ strings of length $m$ whose elements are in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, one of the strings must be repeated twice, which shows it is preperiodic. But how do we show it is purely periodic?

Answer (score 1):

Not only each $m$-tuple defines the unique next value in the sequence, but it also defines the unique **previous** value (modulo $m$, that is). This means that two different sequences can never converge to become eventually identical since some point. Therefore all those $m^m$ strings must go in cycles. There can be no such thing as preperiod.

Really, if we know $x_{i+1}\dots x_{i+m}$, then $x_i\equiv x_{i+m}-x_{i+m-1}-\dots-x_{i+1}\pmod m$. This means we may reconstruct our sequence backward just as well as forward. Now suppose we have a sequence with a preperiod. Let $x_i$ be the last term before the period. What if we find the next $m$ terms and then try to reconstruct the previous one using that formula above? What will it produce: our $x_i$ or the previous term in the period? Remember, it can return only one value.

Comment: How do you know it is unique?

Comment: I mean, when you know $x_{i+1}\dots x_{i+m}$, you can get $x_i$. And yes it is unique, because the result of addition/subtraction mod m is unique.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer and provide examples because I still don't get it.

Comment: the period is of course much less than $m^m$

Comment: Maybe. We don't know that, nor do we care.

Comment: How does it producing the previous term contradict that it is only pre periodic?

Comment: Which previous term would it produce? The previous term in the period or the previous term in the preperiod?

Comment: The previous term in the preperiod. I still don't see the contradiction.

Comment: Suppose you enter the period, do a full cycle (maybe two or three times, just to make sure) and arrive at the same place where you've been just after the preperiod. Suppose you want to go back from there. _Which way is back?_